# Why does soup only shows half of the chart I'm scraping?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping from a google search but I can only get the first row of a two row chart on the right-hand side.

The search query is:
    https://www.google.com/search?q=kegerators

I've noticed that doing an inspect element doesn't really work as beautifulsoup seems to extract a different code.

The code I have is:

```
htmltext=br.open(query).read()
soup=BeautifulSoup(htmltext)
search = soup.findAll("div", attrs={ "class" : "_cf" })
print search
```

Upon looking at the code (basically looking for "b>$" - as I know I should see 8 of those) I only get 4, which happen to be the top row of the chart.

These is the result of the search:

```
[<div class="_cf" style="overflow:hidden"><a href="/aclk?sa=l&amp;ai=CWIBGejcoVcHKGZGRpgODooCoBb_LpL8F97bXuKcB8e3ehoMDCAYQASgEYMnW5YzkpPAToAGZ59TwA8gBB6oEKE_QXQwg4jm9qww0XeiRiHJbw6wjHFr7nFym-P_o8ZOVwV9fsCnuE4TABQWgBiaAB8-Yqw-QBwGoB6a-G9gHAeAS2bP06fCz5Nc4&amp;sig=AOD64_3Nr9FEXmlEe5T0onPnljRVm5cOyg&amp;ctype=5&amp;ved=0CEkQ8w4&amp;adurl=http://105.xg4ken.com/media/redir.php%3Fprof%3D108%26camp%3D435531%26affcode%3Dpg17569%26k_inner_url_encoded%3D1%26cid%3D44811231743%26networkType%3Dsearch%26kdv%3Dc%26kpid%3DKC2000TWIN%26url%3Dhttp://www.kegerator.com/kc2000twin-edgestar-full-size-dual-tap-kegerator-and-keg-beer-cooler/KC2000TWIN.html%253Fmtcpromotion%253DPLA%25253eKegerators%25253eHome_Kegerators%25253eKC2000TWIN%2526src%253DSHOPPING%2526kpid%253DKC2000TWIN%2526CAWELAID%253D120127140000003968%2526CAGPSPN%253Dpla"><span class="_vf" style="height:86px;width:86px"><span class="_uf"></span><img class="_wf" src="http://t3.gstatic.com/shopping?q=tbn:ANd9GcRY5NBoY-anFlJUYExmil81vJG5i1nw6LqVu64lSjw8tSPBUEdh3JaiFix-gfSKMGtE2ZwX8w&amp;usqp=CAc"/></span></a><div style="height:2.4em;overflow:hidden"><a href="/aclk?sa=l&amp;ai=CWIBGejcoVcHKGZGRpgODooCoBb_LpL8F97bXuKcB8e3ehoMDCAYQASgEYMnW5YzkpPAToAGZ59TwA8gBB6oEKE_QXQwg4jm9qww0XeiRiHJbw6wjHFr7nFym-P_o8ZOVwV9fsCnuE4TABQWgBiaAB8-Yqw-QBwGoB6a-G9gHAeAS2bP06fCz5Nc4&amp;sig=AOD64_3Nr9FEXmlEe5T0onPnljRVm5cOyg&amp;ctype=5&amp;ved=0CEoQ9A4&amp;adurl=http://105.xg4ken.com/media/redir.php%3Fprof%3D108%26camp%3D435531%26affcode%3Dpg17569%26k_inner_url_encoded%3D1%26cid%3D44811231743%26networkType%3Dsearch%26kdv%3Dc%26kpid%3DKC2000TWIN%26url%3Dhttp://www.kegerator.com/kc2000twin-edgestar-full-size-dual-tap-kegerator-and-keg-beer-cooler/KC2000TWIN.html%253Fmtcpromotion%253DPLA%25253eKegerators%25253eHome_Kegerators%25253eKC2000TWIN%2526src%253DSHOPPING%2526kpid%253DKC2000TWIN%2526CAWELAID%253D120127140000003968%2526CAGPSPN%253Dpla">EdgeStar Ultra Low Temp F...</a></div><div><b>$599.00</b></div><div><cite style="white-space:nowrap">Kegerator</cite></div></div>, <div class="_cf" style="overflow:hidden"><a href="/aclk?sa=l&amp;ai=Ci3McejcoVcHKGZGRpgODooCoBbq6sIlCuoWHoecBsr7t8p0DCAYQAigEYMnW5YzkpPAToAGGkL__A8gBB6oEJk_QfTSA0wmFk4y2XiFbaDdvaCb5RDCMaCViLKjMXGzPRb25FD96wAUFoAYmgAfi70CQBwGoB6a-G9gHAeAS982vtJaazpcX&amp;sig=AOD64_2p5xKPb7MPCfmN_Ziz8e48c4KUww&amp;ctype=5&amp;ved=0CEwQ8w4&amp;adurl=http://www.beveragefactory.com/draftbeer/kegerators/dualkegerator/Kegco_K199SS-2.html%3FCAWELAID%3D1372129915%26CAGPSPN%3Dpla%26catargetid%3D320012430000210381%26cadevice%3Dc"><span class="_vf" style="height:86px;width:86px"><span class="_uf"></span><img class="_wf" src="http://t3.gstatic.com/shopping?q=tbn:ANd9GcRS4iCsD4EDV37Rg1kZf0nxFK3bYgYaWC-bxMv-ISg4dI8m-COU3ZHCZGs3FdJBK3npkpoE&amp;usqp=CAc"/></span></a><div style="height:2.4em;overflow:hidden"><a href="/aclk?sa=l&amp;ai=Ci3McejcoVcHKGZGRpgODooCoBbq6sIlCuoWHoecBsr7t8p0DCAYQAigEYMnW5YzkpPAToAGGkL__A8gBB6oEJk_QfTSA0wmFk4y2XiFbaDdvaCb5RDCMaCViLKjMXGzPRb25FD96wAUFoAYmgAfi70CQBwGoB6a-G9gHAeAS982vtJaazpcX&amp;sig=AOD64_2p5xKPb7MPCfmN_Ziz8e48c4KUww&amp;ctype=5&amp;ved=0CE0Q9A4&amp;adurl=http://www.beveragefactory.com/draftbeer/kegerators/dualkegerator/Kegco_K199SS-2.html%3FCAWELAID%3D1372129915%26CAGPSPN%3Dpla%26catargetid%3D320012430000210381%26cadevice%3Dc">Kegco K199SS‑2 D...</a></div><div><b>$539.99</b></div><div><cite style="white-space:nowrap">BeverageFa...</cite></div></div>, <div class="_cf" style="overflow:hidden"><a href="/aclk?sa=l&amp;ai=Ce13vejcoVcHKGZGRpgODooCoBbPk-6QGw724_YECm-XCqsADCAYQAygEYMnW5YzkpPAToAGplMD_A8gBB6oEJ0_QHRJU4jm9qww0XeiRiEZql7sjHFr7nFym-P_o8ZPw6FxfsGWezMAFBaAGJoAHv-s_kAcBqAemvhvYBwHgEu3Gi-zTi6KfOA&amp;sig=AOD64_1vJdgw5PE4907iPyxrj9zuf9R2JQ&amp;ctype=5&amp;ved=0CE8Q8w4&amp;adurl=http://105.xg4ken.com/media/redir.php%3Fprof%3D712%26camp%3D467003%26affcode%3Dpg90596%26k_inner_url_encoded%3D1%26cid%3D69286079891%26networkType%3Dsearch%26kdv%3Dc%26kpid%3DKC2000%26url%3Dhttp://www.compactappliance.com/on/demandware.store/Sites-Appliance-Site/default/Product-Show%253Fcgid%253DWine_and_Beverage-Kegerators-Complete_Units%2526mtcpromotion%253DPLA%25253eWine_and_Beverage%25253eKegerators-Complete_Units%25253eKC2000%2526prod%253DKC2000%2526showGrid%253Dtrue%2526src%253DSHOPPING%2526CAWELAID%253D120128510000023186%2526CAGPSPN%253Dpla"><span class="_vf" style="height:86px;width:86px"><span class="_uf"></span><img class="_wf" src="http://t2.gstatic.com/shopping?q=tbn:ANd9GcSkf6-jVZt34pd_6QyqZGre06VxszvFZX70-wUOEDRhEFhorX_Yek0oyr-5jvk8FNpj2KWusQ&amp;usqp=CAc"/></span></a><div style="height:2.4em;overflow:hidden"><a href="/aclk?sa=l&amp;ai=Ce13vejcoVcHKGZGRpgODooCoBbPk-6QGw724_YECm-XCqsADCAYQAygEYMnW5YzkpPAToAGplMD_A8gBB6oEJ0_QHRJU4jm9qww0XeiRiEZql7sjHFr7nFym-P_o8ZPw6FxfsGWezMAFBaAGJoAHv-s_kAcBqAemvhvYBwHgEu3Gi-zTi6KfOA&amp;sig=AOD64_1vJdgw5PE4907iPyxrj9zuf9R2JQ&amp;ctype=5&amp;ved=0CFAQ9A4&amp;adurl=http://105.xg4ken.com/media/redir.php%3Fprof%3D712%26camp%3D467003%26affcode%3Dpg90596%26k_inner_url_encoded%3D1%26cid%3D69286079891%26networkType%3Dsearch%26kdv%3Dc%26kpid%3DKC2000%26url%3Dhttp://www.compactappliance.com/on/demandware.store/Sites-Appliance-Site/default/Product-Show%253Fcgid%253DWine_and_Beverage-Kegerators-Complete_Units%2526mtcpromotion%253DPLA%25253eWine_and_Beverage%25253eKegerators-Complete_Units%25253eKC2000%2526prod%253DKC2000%2526showGrid%253Dtrue%2526src%253DSHOPPING%2526CAWELAID%253D120128510000023186%2526CAGPSPN%253Dpla">EdgeStar Ultra Low Temp F...</a></div><div><b>$499.00</b></div><div><cite style="white-space:nowrap">Compact Ap...</cite></div></div>, <div class="_cf" style="overflow:hidden"><a href="/aclk?sa=l&amp;ai=Cy3_IejcoVcHKGZGRpgODooCoBbPohPQF-_S47OYB-9mp9owDCAYQBCgEYMnW5YzkpPAToAGXkZL_A8gBB6oEJU_QTQDP0wmFk4y2XiFbHQAEQCb5RDCMaCViLKjMXHFSpFtiXuTABQWgBiaAB9HubZAHAagHpr4b2AcB4BK83bWOpaqlwDc&amp;sig=AOD64_1K1ZPCbZMwuzxoJ5_LJFXg2X4coA&amp;ctype=5&amp;ved=0CFIQ8w4&amp;adurl=http://www.maxtool.com/stainless-steel-keggermeister-beer-refrigerator-4649%3Fgoogle%3D1%26CAWELAID%3D230005740000000943%26CAGPSPN%3Dpla"><span class="_vf" style="height:86px;width:86px"><span class="_uf"></span><img class="_wf" src="http://t1.gstatic.com/shopping?q=tbn:ANd9GcTf56EQ6DVbOk02D7cLgVmlurU-2gNrhD6a74MnzQBWg1W290DTYQuj0sSUxQEbxo1XO6pB&amp;usqp=CAc"/></span></a><div style="height:2.4em;overflow:hidden"><a href="/aclk?sa=l&amp;ai=Cy3_IejcoVcHKGZGRpgODooCoBbPohPQF-_S47OYB-9mp9owDCAYQBCgEYMnW5YzkpPAToAGXkZL_A8gBB6oEJU_QTQDP0wmFk4y2XiFbHQAEQCb5RDCMaCViLKjMXHFSpFtiXuTABQWgBiaAB9HubZAHAagHpr4b2AcB4BK83bWOpaqlwDc&amp;sig=AOD64_1K1ZPCbZMwuzxoJ5_LJFXg2X4coA&amp;ctype=5&amp;ved=0CFMQ9A4&amp;adurl=http://www.maxtool.com/stainless-steel-keggermeister-beer-refrigerator-4649%3Fgoogle%3D1%26CAWELAID%3D230005740000000943%26CAGPSPN%3Dpla">FunTime Black Kegge...</a></div><div><b>$399.99</b></div><div><cite style="white-space:nowrap">Max Tool</cite></div></div>]
```

Is Google doing something strange here?

Comment: Some of the code renders after JavaScript code is executed. That might be resulting in mismatch between the element tree of browser view and scraper view.

Comment: Looks like you're correct. I tried using Selenium and on the browser I can see exactly 4. If i  use a normal browser I get 8. I tried using PhantomJS but I think I need to render it manually.. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why results might differ is that Google displays different results on each request, e.g. sometimes it could get 10 shopping results, sometimes 7 or 4.

Specifying `gl` (*country, e.g: us*), `hl` (*language, e.g: en*) query params could get exact or close to the exact result that you see in your browser.

Also, don't forget to specify a `user-agent`, otherwise, Google will block your requests eventually.

Code and [example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Google-Scrape-Inline-Shopping-pythonserpapi#main.py):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent":
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36"
    "(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

params = {
  "q": "buy coffe", # intentional grammatical error to display right side shopping results
  "hl": "en",
  "gl": "us"
}

response = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search", headers=headers, params=params)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

# scrapes both top and right side shopping resutls
for result in soup.select('.pla-hovercard-content-ellip'):
    title = result.select_one('.pymv4e').text
    link = result.select_one('.pla-hovercard-content-ellip a.tkXAec')['href']
    ad_link = f"https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead{result.select_one('.pla-hovercard-content-ellip a')['href']}"
    price = result.select_one('.qptdjc').text
    try:
      rating = result.select_one('.Fam1ne.tPhRLe')["aria-label"].replace("Rated ", "").replace(" out of ", "").replace(",", "")
    except:
      rating = None

    try:
      reviews = result.select_one('.GhQXkc').text.replace("(", "").replace(")", "")
    except:
      reviews = None

    source = result.select_one('.zPEcBd.LnPkof').text.strip()

    print(f'{title}\n{link}\n{ad_link}\n{price}\n{rating}\n{reviews}\n{source}\n')

-------------
'''
MUD\WTR | Mushroom Coffee Replacement, 90 servings
https://mudwtr.com/collections/shop/products/90-serving-bag
https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/aclk?sa=l&ai=DChcSEwj5p8u-2rzyAhV2yJQJHfzhBoUYABAHGgJ5bQ&sig=AOD64_3NGBzLzkTv61K7kSrD2f9AREHH_g&ctype=5&q=&ved=2ahUKEwji7MK-2rzyAhWaaM0KHcnaDDcQ9aACegQIAhBo&adurl=
$125.00
4.85
1k+
mudwtr.com
...
'''
```

---

Alternatively, you can do the same thing using [Google Inline Shopping API](https://serpapi.com/inline-shopping) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The difference is that everything is already extracted, and all that needs to be done is just to iterate over structured JSON.

Code to integrate:

```py
import json, os
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
  "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
  "engine": "google",
  "q": "buy coffe",
  "hl": "en",
  "gl": "us",
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

for result in results['shopping_results']:
    print(json.dumps(result, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))

--------
'''
{
  "position": 1,
  "block_position": "right",
  "title": "Maxwell House Original Roast | 48oz",
  "price": "$10.49",
  "extracted_price": 10.49,
  "link": "https://www.google.com/aclk?sa=l&ai=DChcSEwiGn8aT2rzyAhXgyZQJHZHdBJMYABAEGgJ5bQ&ae=2&sig=AOD64_0jBjdUIMeqJvrXYxn4NGcpwCYrJQ&ctype=5&q=&ved=2ahUKEwiOxLmT2rzyAhWiFVkFHWMNAaEQ5bgDegQIAhBa&adurl=",
  "source": "Boxed",
  "rating": 4.6,
  "reviews": 2000,
  "thumbnail": "https://serpapi.com/searches/611e1b2cfdca3e6a1c9335e6/images/e4ae7f31164ec52021f1c04d8be4e4bda2138b1acd12c868052125eb86ead292.png"
}
...
'''
```

P.S - I wrote a blog post about this topic that you can find [here](https://dev.to/dimitryzub/scrape-google-inline-shopping-results-with-python-35cd).

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.